# How to Use Overtone with Vimclojure?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, vimclojure, supercollider

I use SuperCollider with [Overtone](http://overtone.github.com/),and VimClojure.
But,it don't work well...What is Problem?

"lein repl" works.

```
user -> (use 'overtone.live)
```

project.clj

```
(defproject overtone-tutorial "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[overtone "0.5.0"]])
```

**Error**

Start Vim

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'vimclojure.nails/NamespaceOfFile

And NGServer

> Warning: *repls* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *repls* or change the name.
>
> Warning: *print-pretty* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *print-pretty* or change the name.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [a newer release of VimClojure](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2501). The trouble stems from some changes in Clojure 1.3 regarding dynamic Vars.

Comment: I am using the VimClojure 2.3.1 (most recent at time of writing) and seeing the same error.  I am using org.clojars.scott/lein-nailgun "1.1.0" for nailgun.

Comment: @raoul I cannot guarantee for third party packages from clojars. Please try the nailgun server delivered with VimClojure http://clojars.org/vimclojure/server manually and see if this fixes things. If so, the error is not in VimClojure. If not, please open a ticket in the tracker on bitbucket. Thanks.

Comment: That worked a treat thanks :)  Incidentally for anyone else using lein and vimclojure: the alias here: http://groups.google.com/group/vimclojure/msg/ebfba35627bec25f makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but Sam Aaron uses emacs.  Personally, I find a combination of his live coding setup (https://github.com/overtone/live-coding-emacs) and evil (http://gitorious.org/evil) pretty pleasant for a vim head like me.

Comment: Can you share how you set up evil for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I am using [vim-fireplace](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace) with Overtone. It's more than adequate for simple hacking.